# Two wordpress installs conflicting

Tags: php, wordpress

We are trying to run two separate word press blogs on our site right now and getting some issues.

We have word press installed at www.example.com/updates/ and www.example.com/blogs/

/blogs/ was our original install and always worked fine. I did a fresh install of the most up to date version of WP in our /updates/ directory and the installation seemed to go just fine.

The problem we are having is some awful redirection/session confusion and other madness that I just can't seem to get under control. Because we are trying to get the newest installation just like the /blogs/ one, I login to both of them frequently to check and copy setting etc.

Many times I will be logged into wp-admin for blogs, and it all of the sudden kicks me out and puts me at the login page for /updates/

Similarly, when I browse the site from a non-admin side, if I am logged into /updates/ and I go to view /blogs/ it tries to redirect me to /updates/!

Clearly there are some settings or something making this all kind of messy, can someone point me in the right direction as to where to look for issues?

.htaccess files added:
//for updates------------------

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /updates/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /updates/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

//for blogs---------------------

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blogs/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blogs/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you post what you have in the settings > general section of both Wordpress installs?

Comment: There is not really anything of significance there? Just date and time settings? The URL's for both installs are what they are supposed to be.

Comment: Bad URL settings is the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Yeah, exactly as they should be for each site..hmmmmmm

Comment: Post it anyway. Also post both .htaccess files.

Comment: .htaccess added in original post.

Comment: And at the root? Any `index.php` or `.htaccess`?